# Unable to find a solution or workaround

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, isnull, correlated-subquery

SQL Server 2008 and above.

Suppose I have a Database table named 'Teachers' which contains Details of Teachers in a school and another Table named 'Schedules' which contains their Schedules. Sometimes if I require to automatically assign few hours to a teacher/teachers on a particular day randomly like when one teacher is absent then another teacher can take that available time.

Like here :

```
Declare @hrs numeric(24, 6) = 3

SELECT T_Code 
FROM Teachers 
LEFT JOIN Schedules S
WHERE (SELECT 8 - ISNULL(SUM(S_HOURS),0) AS AVLHRS
        FROM  Schedules 
        WHERE S_Teacher = S.S_Teacher)  < @hrs
ORDER BY ISNULL(S_HOURS,0), NEWID()
```

But the problem here is that only those Teachers who are scheduled are calculated so i am not getting list of all the Teachers available. Like suppose I have a new teacher who is not even scheduled also want to order it in the desc order of hours left by that teacher. Then this won't show that Teacher but I also want that teacher to be seen. I am unable to find the work around.

PS. This is not the complete code and it checks many other conditions but this is the only condition causing problem and I can not show the complete code.

Comment: I assume that new teachers don't have a schedulue. If so then you are filtering them out because of the `(INNER) JOIN`

Comment: They are filtered out even with left join because of subquery

Answer (score 2):

Use `LEFT JOIN` this will bring the all Teacher Records

```
SELECT T_Code 
FROM Teachers 
LEFT JOIN Schedules S ON Teachers.ID = S.TeacherID
AND (SELECT 8 - ISNULL(SUM(S_HOURS),0) AS AVLHRS
       FROM  Schedules 
       WHERE S_Teacher = S.S_Teacher)  < @hrs
ORDER BY ISNULL(S_HOURS,0), NEWID()
```

Updated :

```
SELECT T_Code,
       ISNULL(TmpTable.AVLHRS,0)  AVLHRS  
FROM Teachers 
LEFT JOIN Schedules S ON Teachers.ID = S.TeacherID
OUTER APPLY(
   SELECT 8 - ISNULL(SUM(S_HOURS),0) AS AVLHRS
   FROM  Schedules 
   WHERE S_Teacher = S.S_Teacher
)TmpTable
WHERE  TmpTable.AVLHRS < @hrs
ORDER BY AVLHRS
```

Comment: Tried the left join but the problem rests inside the subquery and not the join itself

Comment: Have you tried exact query, there is no where clause at all

Comment: Tried. Thanks. Worked.

Comment: but I have no clue how to add the question as completed and the reply as solution

Comment: But how can i order it as per 'AVLHRS'?

Comment: when i posted i was not getting the value i.e. i was getting value as 'null'.

Comment: And it's taking up the same teacher when i try the first query even when her hours are exhausted.

Comment: Error : A select statement that assigns value to a variable must not be combined with data retrieval options. Also i don't want it in retrieval part. I want it in query part so i can deduce how much hours she has left and then order it according to the left hours with the highest remaining hours on top

Comment: If you have new requirement then you should ask another question with details, that will be more clear to understand your business requirement.

Comment: That's not new question. It was in where clause. where is for condition.

Answer (score 1):

To display all teachers, whether or not they have a schedule, you have to use a LEFT JOIN. A LEFT JOIN displays all the data of the left table (in your case teachers) even if it doesn't have a value on the right table (in your case schedules).

In your code this looks like this:

```
SELECT T_Code from Teachers LEFT JOIN Schedules S
WHERE (SELECT 8 - ISNULL(SUM(S_HOURS),0) AS AVLHRS
FROM  Schedules WHERE S_Teacher = S.S_Teacher)  < @hrs
ORDER BY ISNULL(S_HOURS,0), NEWID()
```

Comment: Tried the left join but the problem rests inside the subquery and not the join itself